# Spark dataframe with complex & nested data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have 3 dataframes currently
Call them dfA, dfB, and dfC

dfA has 3 cols

---

### |Id | Name | Age |

dfB has say 5 cols. the 2nd col, is a FK reference back to dFA record.

---

### |Id | AId | Street | City | Zip |

Similarily dfC has 3 cols, also with a reference back to dfA

---

### |Id  | AId  |  SomeField  |

Using Spark SQL i can do an JOIN across the 3

```
%sql

SELECT * FROM dfA
INNER JOIN dfB ON dfA.Id = dfB.AId
INNER JOIN dfC ON dfA.Id = dfC.AId
```

And I'll get my resultset, but it's been "flattened" as SQL would do with tabular results like this.

I want to load it in to a complex schema like this

```
val destinationSchema = new StructType()
  .add("id", IntegerType)
  .add("name", StringType)
  .add("age", StringType)
  .add("b", 
       new StructType()
        .add("street", DoubleType, true)
        .add("city", StringType, true)
    .add("zip", StringType, true)
      )
  .add("c",
       new StructType()
        .add("somefield", StringType, true)
      )
```

Any ideas how to take the results of the SELECT and save to dataframe with specifying the schema?

I ultimately want to save the complex StructType, or JSON, and load this is to Mongo DB using the Mongo Spark Connector.

Or, is there a better way to accomplish this from the 3 seperate dataframes (which were originally 3 seperate CSV files that were read in)?

Comment: A (bad) way to solve this: https://imgur.com/a/aDtB4HY
Can the join itself be in scala?

Comment: "Can the join itself be in scala" Sure, I don't see why not. I don't have to use sql.

Answer (score 1):

given three dataframes, loaded in from csv files, you can do this:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val destDF = atableDF
  .join(btableDF, atableDF("id") === btableDF("id")).drop(btableDF("id"))
  .join(ctableDF, atableDF("id") === ctableDF("id")).drop(ctableDF("id"))
  .select($"id",$"name",$"age",struct($"street",$"city",$"zip") as "b",struct($"somefield") as "c")

val jsonDestDF = destDF.select(to_json(struct($"*")).as("row"))
```

which will output:

```
row
"{""id"":100,""name"":""John"",""age"":""43"",""b"":{""street"":""Dark Road"",""city"":""Washington"",""zip"":""98002""},""c"":{""somefield"":""appples""}}"
"{""id"":101,""name"":""Sally"",""age"":""34"",""b"":{""street"":""Light Ave"",""city"":""Los Angeles"",""zip"":""90210""},""c"":{""somefield"":""bananas""}}"
"{""id"":102,""name"":""Damian"",""age"":""23"",""b"":{""street"":""Short Street"",""city"":""New York"",""zip"":""70701""},""c"":{""somefield"":""pears""}}"
```

Comment: need to include .agg(collect_set()) so that i end up with an array of nested items, but thanks. this is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

the previous one worked if all the records had a 1:1 relationship.

here is how you can achieve it for 1:M  (hint: use collect_set to group rows)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val destDF = atableDF
  .join(btableDF, atableDF("id") === btableDF("id")).drop(btableDF("id"))
  .join(ctableDF, atableDF("id") === ctableDF("id")).drop(ctableDF("id"))
  .groupBy($"id",$"name",$"age")
  .agg(collect_set(struct($"street",$"city",$"zip")) as "b",collect_set(struct($"somefield")) as "c")

val jsonDestDF = destDF.select(to_json(struct($"*")).as("row"))

display(jsonDestDF)
```

which will give you the following output:

```
row
"{""id"":102,""name"":""Damian"",""age"":""23"",""b"":[{""street"":""Short Street"",""city"":""New York"",""zip"":""70701""}],""c"":[{""somefield"":""pears""},{""somefield"":""pineapples""}]}"
"{""id"":100,""name"":""John"",""age"":""43"",""b"":[{""street"":""Dark Road"",""city"":""Washington"",""zip"":""98002""}],""c"":[{""somefield"":""appples""}]}"
"{""id"":101,""name"":""Sally"",""age"":""34"",""b"":[{""street"":""Light Ave"",""city"":""Los Angeles"",""zip"":""90210""}],""c"":[{""somefield"":""grapes""},{""somefield"":""peaches""},{""somefield"":""bananas""}]}"
```

sample data I used just in case anyone wants to play:

atable.csv

```
100,"John",43
101,"Sally",34
102,"Damian",23
104,"Rita",14
105,"Mohit",23
```

btable.csv:

```
100,"Dark Road","Washington",98002
101,"Light Ave","Los Angeles",90210
102,"Short Street","New York",70701
104,"Long Drive","Buffalo",80345
105,"Circular Quay","Orlando",65403
```

ctable.csv:

```
100,"appples"
101,"bananas"
102,"pears"
101,"grapes"
102,"pineapples"
101,"peaches"
```